# Is there any specific statement in order for the BeautifulSoup to scrape properly?

Tags: web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I was trying to scrape the table from Wikipedia. I tried to pass the ('div', class_ = 'mw-parser-output') and it returned a text. But why is it that table tag returned an empty list? Please explain. Thank you.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HwzLs.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To scrape the second table from the wiki page, you can use this example:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Makati'

soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, 'html.parser')

second_table = soup.select('.wikitable')[1]
for tr in second_table.select('tr'):
    print('{:<25} {:<25} {:<25} {:<25} {:<25}'.format(*[t.get_text(strip=True) for t in tr.select('th, td')]))
```

Prints:

```
Barangay                  Population (2004)         Population (2010)[51]     Area (km2)                District                 
Bangkal                   22,433                    23,378                    0.74                      1st                      
Bel-Air                   9,330                     18,280                    1.71                      1st                      
Carmona                   3,699                     3,096                     0.34                      1st                      
Cembo                     25,815                    27,998                    0.22                      2nd                      
Comembo                   14,174                    14,433                    0.27                      2nd                      
Dasmariñas                5,757                     5,654                     1.90                      1st                      
East Rembo                23,902                    26,433                    0.44                      2nd                      
Forbes Park               3,420                     2,533                     2.53                      1st                      
Guadalupe Nuevo           22,493                    18,271                    0.57                      2nd                      
Guadalupe Viejo           13,632                    16,411                    0.62                      2nd                      

... and so on.
```